# PHP - Processing after input is entered twice in a row

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with my form.

I have an HTML Form as follows:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form>
```

**Now my problem is:**

Every time I process this form for the first time, it should output an error. The error has to be shown every time, if this is the first try.

If I enter the same input value twice, it should succeed.

I thought about setting a session variable `$_SESSION['first_visit]` if I'm processing the form for the first time.

I also thought about saving the $_POST['text'] - Value into Session but it's being overwritten every time.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

extract($_POST);

if( isset($send) )
{
    if( $fired <= 0 )
    {
        $fired++;
        echo "Nope, error. send again to succeed";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Yay success";
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="fired" value="<?php echo isset($fired) ? $fired : 0 ?>">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form>
```

Here's some quick and dirty snippet. We set a hidden input field with an initial value of `0` and count it up everytime the form has been send. The only thing to do afterwards is to check if the value of the hidden field is bigger than `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies instead of session

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="exampleForm">
   <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
   <input type="button" value="Send" name="send" onClick="checkVisit()">
</form>

<script>

   function checkVisit(){
      var isFirstVisit = getCookie("first_visit");
      if(isFirstVisit  == "" || isFirstVisit  == 1){
         setCookie("first_visit",0,1);
      }else if (isFirstVisit == 0){
         setCookie("first_visit",1,1);
         document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this fast Answer! Your Tipp helped me with my problem a lot.

Here is the working Script:

```html
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['go'])) {

 $text =  $_POST['text'];
 $fired = $_POST['fired'];

 if($fired <= 0) {

  $fired++;
  echo "Nope";
  $_SESSION['val'] = $_POST['text'];

 }
 else {
  if($fired > 0 && $_SESSION['val'] == $_POST['text'] ) {
   echo "Success";
  }
  else {
   echo "Failed";
   $_SESSION['val'] = $_POST['text'];
   }
 }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
 <input type="hidden" name="fired" value="<?php echo isset($fired) ? $fired : 0 ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="val" id="val" value="">
 <input type="submit" value="Senden" name="go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```